# Use a anchor tag as a post method?

Tags: php, html, sql, post, get

So, I'm trying to make a template type page that when a user clicks a product link, it takes them to the page and the php script auto-fills the page with the product info in the placeholders. The problem I'm having is I don't know how to make the product picture a link to the template page AND carry over a post method to let the php script know which product data to pull from the prelaoded array that I filled with product data from the php sql query. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use a form that posts to the template page with an image button to submit it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image

Comment: Awesome! Do you think that method will pose any security issues? This is for a client's eccomerce website. (payments are third party)

Comment: It's just a form. No extra security issues than you would normally have with a form

Comment: Honestly I would just use a link with the product id in the query string rather than trying to post to the template page. Having the product id in the URL seems like it would have some advantages, like if a user wanted to bookmark a product, for example.

Comment: Excelent Idea. Thanks a ton my guy!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're mentioning anchors, that is a bad idea. They are usually encoded in the URL behind the hash sign (#) and **not** sent to the server.

So, one way to do it, is to either include the relevant data in the form content, e.g. in a hidden field.

Or another way would be to append it as a query parameter to the URL.

Hope that helps, and not taking security into account (e.g. both methods make it easy to perform SQL injection, or the parameters could be used to display something you don't want the user to select because it's out of stock, etc. pp.)!

Comment: Thanks my guy! Super insightful. :) You rock!

Answer (score 0):

since you're mentioning anchors with post, in my opinion this is not possible but one way to do it, is that using jquery and ajax.

see below link:
[you can find the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60729080/how-to-send-the-value-of-an-anchor-with-jquery-ajax-to-php)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32291615)